# Is it possible to reference a variable that has just been previously destructed as the default value for Destructuring Assignment?

Tags: javascript

I have a question about `Destructuring assignment` in ECMAScript.

Is it possible to reference a variable that has just been previously destructed as the default value?

```js
function doSomething({ requiredProp, optionalProp = requiredProp }) {
}
```

Is there a guarantee of evaluation order in the spec? From looking at the transpiled code to ES5 with Babel or tsc, this seems to work.

Comment: Yes, that sort of code is fine. It might be [specified here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation) on step 28 but I'm not entirely sure

Comment: Yes, it is possible without any issues.
Just make sure the destructured variable to be used as default value gets declared first